# Application is not launching

Tags: android

I just changed the main activity name after creating the app and updated the same in Manifest file.
But now the app is getting built without any error, its not at all getting launched. Here is what i get as output in eclips

> [2012-05-05 21:32:12 - Test] Performing sync [2012-05-05
>   21:32:12 - Test] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD
>   'Test_G' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554' [2012-05-05 21:32:12
>   - Test] Uploading Test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' [2012-05-05 21:32:12 - Test] Installing Test.apk...
>   [2012-05-05 21:32:15 - Test] Success! [2012-05-05
>   21:32:16 - Test] \Test\binTest.apk installed on device
>   [2012-05-05 21:32:16 - Test] Done!

How to solve this

Manifest.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="contactListTab"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you post the android manifest file? This information says your apps is launching.

Comment: Manifest file is added.. please see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the intent category. Try adding

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Between the acitivity tags!

Comment: yes, you are right. I did but my app started working only appending . (dot) to activity. why so?... pls ref my comment for the below ans and provide me the reason

Comment: The dot is a shorform. You could either write "package.name.Activity" or just use ".Activity" so that OS knows which file it needs to execute

Answer (score 1):

Your activity declaration isn't saying it should be the first activity that should be opened after the app starts to do this you have to add the intent filters and you're activity name should be . because it's a java file in the package. And as mentioned in the other answer you have to set the `package=""` to the package name of your app.

Try changing your manifest to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="-->PACKAGE NAME<--"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".contactListTab">
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ensure the activityname is contactListTab!

Comment: Why is it require to append dot to activity name i.e why .contactListTab instead we can write simply contactListTab. But it does not work.. May i know the reason please

Comment: The dot is to define that you're using a file in the Android package of your app. It could also be in another package which could have another name.

Answer (score 0):

```
package="Test"
```

Instead of `Test`, put the package where your Activity resides. Also make sure `contactListTab` is your `Activity`.

I suggest you declaring such strings in your *res/strings.xml* file instead of having them here. This way changing them is easier.

Comment: After appending .(dot) to my activity and adding  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> lines of code it started working
But why cant default editor put these?... why the dot is required?

Comment: The dot is shorthand for the full package name, so you don't have to explicitly type it again.  I would not trust the xml gui editor - you can let it try to add things, but may need to manually edit the actual xml code if it corrupts things.